# Loading javascript on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a `javascript` with me and just trying to load that on my `UIWebView`,Can't figure out what i am doing wrong.
Here is my Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>(function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = 'https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript'; document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) { var w = new PCWidget({ c: 'ea5935c8-1f44-4172-bcd7-18d6f316ad75', f: true }); done = true; } }; })();</script>
```

And Here is my code:

```
NSString *temp =@"<script type='text/javascript'>(function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = 'https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript'; document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) { var w = new PCWidget({ c: 'ea5935c8-1f44-4172-bcd7-18d6f316ad75', f: true }); done = true; } }; })();</script>";
    
[_mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:temp];
```

Here is my blank `webView`...:(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the script tag in the javascript. `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` tries to execute the given javascript string directly in the webview.

Try it this way:

```
NSString *temp =@"(function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = 'https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript'; document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) { var w = new PCWidget({ c: 'ea5935c8-1f44-4172-bcd7-18d6f316ad75', f: true }); done = true; } }; })();";
```

Comment: @AyanKhan   are you loading the webview before calling this javascript? Does it have content or is it blank?

Comment: i am doing this way: [mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:temp];
    [self.view addSubview:mainWebView];

Comment: This is the html dom after the javascript executes. It seems one of the script files' src is wrong. Check line 45 of WidgetScript

`<html>
<head>
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript"></script><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetVersions/ea5935c8-1f44-4172-bcd7-18d6f316ad75/_WidgetJPCB0"></script><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="undefined/VisitorWidget/Widget/ea5935c8-1f44-4172-bcd7-18d6f316ad75/undefined/_WidgetJPCB1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`